# Taking an index out of const char* argument

Tags: c++, c, string

I have the following code:

```
int some_array[256] = { ... };

int do_stuff(const char* str)
{
   int index = *str;
   return some_array[index];
}
```

Apparently the above code causes a bug in some platforms, because *str can in fact be negative.

So I thought of two possible solutions:

1. Casting the value on assignment (`unsigned int index = (unsigned char)*str;`).
2. Passing `const unsigned char*` instead.

Edit: The rest of this question did not get a treatment, so I moved it to a new thread.

Comment: Why you are passing index as string? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Really?   Why do you want to pass a `char *` to a function, and use what it points at as an index into a static array?

Comment: ".. *str can in fact be negative" should not be a bug. If the calling code does not handle it correctly, the bug is there, not in this snippet.

Comment: @Raw N - even a technique that is slightly decent would be an improvement.

Comment: @qrdl I try to reduce the question to minimum. The actual code does a deep packet inspection on uses the 1st payload byte as a key to a fixed 256 bytes dictionary.

Comment: @qrdl: a `char` _could_ hold a negative value, if said `char` was used to store a byte. The C99 standard mentions this as implementation-defined behaviour: _"An object declared as type char is large enough to store any member of the basic execution character set. If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a char object, its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative. If any other character is stored in a char object, the resulting value is implementation-defined but shall be within the range of values that can be represented in that type."_

Comment: @qrdl: Lookup tables for string operations are a very important implementation technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Characters are allowed to be signed or unsigned, depending on the platform. An assumption of unsigned range is what causes your bug.

Your `do_stuff` code does not treat `const char*` as a string representation. It uses it as a sequence of byte-sized indexes into a look-up table. Therefore, there is nothing wrong with forcing `unsigned char` type on the characters of your string inside `do_stuff` (i.e. use your solution #1). This keeps re-interpretation of `char` as an index localized to the implementation of `do_stuff` function.

Of course, this assumes that other parts of your code do treat `str` as a C string.

Answer (score 5):

The signedness of `char` is indeed platform-dependent, but what you do know is that there are as many values of `char` as there are of `unsigned char`, and the conversion is injective. So you can absolutely cast the value to associate a lookup index with each character:

```
unsigned char idx = *str;
return arr[idx];
```

You should of course make sure that the `arr` has at least `UCHAR_MAX + 1` elements. (This may cause hilarious edge cases when `sizeof(unsigned long long int) == 1`, which is fortunately rare.)

Comment: Actually, the protocol uses octets, so you only need to make sure that the array has 256 elements. It doesn't matter if `UCHAR_MAX>255` because no possible input can contain such values.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, I was going to say that - if you have information on the expected input, you can restrict the lookup table to that (and assert).